# Intersecting two lists with nested lists inside

Tags: python, r

I have a file with two columns. Every row includes one entry or multiple entries. I want to intersect entries of every single row of one column with the other one, keeping in mind that for multiple entry rows we need just a hit. By multiple column I mean in the following example the second element of List A which is made by two entries (gene2 and gene3)

for example:

```
A=[gene1, [gene2, gene3], gene 4]
B=[gene1, gene2]
```

the intersecting set would be:

```
C=[gene1, gene2]
```

gene2 is chosen even though in list A is part of a group that includes also gene3. So when we hit a multiple entry like the list [gene2, gene3] in list A we are going to evaluate any single element of it with the elements of the other lists (gene2 OR gene 3).

If we have to evaluate a list of elements from both lists to get a match again they just need to have one element in common so:

```
A=[gene1, [gene2, gene3]]
B=[gene1, [gene2, gene4]]
C=[gene1, gene2] #intersecting set
```

All of this comes from the fact that I have two columns of genes I want a venn diagram, however some rows have multiple entries and of these last ones I just need one element to match with the rest.

Finally I need also the original lists back (A and B, called newA and newB respectively) in my example with all the elements and list of elements that did not match with anything like:

```
A=[gene1, [gene2, gene3]]
B=[gene1, [gene2, gene4],[gene5, gene6], gene7]
C=[gene1, gene2] #intersecting A and B
newA=empty #because gene3 was together with gene 2 that matched
newB=[[gene5, gene6], gene7]
```

notice that gene3 does not get included in the newA because it was in a list of multiple choices with gene2 that was chosen...same for gene4 in newB.

Comment: flatten the lists and run a regular intersection?

Comment: I believe the following functions will help you: `?purrr::flatten()`, `?base::setdiff()`, `?base::intersect()'